# Sharepoint 2013 Online Development options without Sharepoint Designer/Deployment Capabilities?

Tags: 2013

Due to corporate rules regarding what people are able to have access to, I do not have any type of Sharepoint Designer or Deployment capabilities.

Currently I am able to develop using Sharepoint as a UI by using a content editor and linking it to an index.html page with a all of my javascript on it and then just developing it like I would a normal Angular SPA, but I would like to figure out a way to integrate ASP.net with it if possible.

I know my options are limited regarding what I am able to do, but I do have Visual Studio 2017 and can develop Sharepoint Web Parts, although I am unsure if I could actually integrate them with the access I have, etc...

Is it possible to do anything other than what I am doing regarding development in Sharepoint?

Comment: Are you able to upload web parts to your site?

Comment: @jpollar It appears I am still able to upload a webpart...I was able to click "Choose a webpart to upload" and it opened a file browser where I could select a file.  What will creating custom webparts allow me to do?